# Substitution with $a = x$, $b=\frac{y-x^2}{x} $ in differential equation gives me $ u = a \frac{\partial u}{\partial a} $ - Why?

Tags: derivatives, substitution

If

$$
\cases{a = x\\
b=\frac{y-x^2}{x}}
$$

and

$$
x\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}+\left(y+x^2\right)\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}=u
$$

Why do we get

$$
u = a \frac{\partial u}{\partial a}
$$

Comment: Please avoid multi-line formulas on the title; it messes up lists and some displays, and are almost never necessary.

Comment: Why $\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial u}{\partial a}\frac{\partial a}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial u}{\partial b}\frac{\partial b}{\partial x}$ and not $\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial u}{\partial a}\frac{\partial a}{\partial x}$?

Answer (score 0):

**HINTS:**

Use the chain rule [see this example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule#Example)

$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial u}{\partial a}\frac{\partial a}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial u}{\partial b}\frac{\partial b}{\partial x}$$

and

$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}=\frac{\partial u}{\partial a}\frac{\partial a}{\partial y}+\frac{\partial u}{\partial b}\frac{\partial b}{\partial y}$$

Note that $x=a$, $y=ab+a^2$, $\frac{\partial a}{\partial x}=1$, $\frac{\partial a}{\partial y}=0$, $\frac{\partial b}{\partial y}=-2-b/a$, and $\frac{\partial b}{\partial x}=1/a$.

Comment: Why $\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial u}{\partial a}\frac{\partial a}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial u}{\partial b}\frac{\partial b}{\partial x}$ and not $\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial u}{\partial a}\frac{\partial a}{\partial x}+$?

Comment: $u$ depends on $x$ and $y$ and $x$ and $y$ depend on $a$ and $b$.

Comment: I don't get it to be honest

Comment: Have you learned the chain rule for a function of two variables each of which depends on two variables?

Comment: I don't get it why it should depend on the chain rule in the first place. Also, I don't see it here being applied. The chain rule as I know it is (fg)' = f'g + fg'. See your Edit right now: No, i haven't

Comment: That rule is called the product rule.  If you don't know the chain rule, why are you studying PDE's?

Comment: I've provided a link that explains the chain rule.  And I've given you the equations to apply.  Just use those along with the expressions in the last sentence (the one that begins with "Note").

Comment: @student Please let me know how I can improve my answer. I really want to give you the best answer I can. If it was not useful, then I can simply delete this answer if you prefer.